# How to open a street view in virtual reality mode programmatically?

Tags: android, google-street-view

Using the following code I open a street view of a particular location using its latitude and longitude.

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=27.173891,78.042068" + "&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=8"));
startActivity(streetView);
```

When the street view of that location appears I need to double tap on the rotating arrow icon to the bottom right of the screen to get to the virtual reality mode, but I want to directly view the street view in virtual reality mode without the double tap.

Is this possible? How can I programmatically achieve it? Thanks.