# Open Street View App in Cardboard enabled mode

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to open Google Street View app in Cardboard mode from my app using intents. I know that it is possible to open it in panaromic mode by the following lines of code.

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=27.173891,78.042068" + "&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=8"));
startActivity(streetView);
```

I looked at Cardboard app and it contains "BasicStreetViewApp" that shows map in Cardboard mode.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448529/how-to-open-a-street-view-in-virtual-reality-mode-programmatically) has been asked in past, but nobody answered it. 
Kindly guide me how to solve the issue.